# AngularJS update service variable on diff controller's methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just started my first app with AngularJS and I'm having an issue with service variables.
HTML:

```
<html ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <head>
        <title>{{ page.title() }}</title>
        ...
    </head>
<body>
    <header>{{page.title()}}</header>
    <main ng-view></main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

*Inside each view I use ng-controller="SomeCtrl"
MainCtrl:

```
APP.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, page, uri){
    $scope.page = page;
    $scope.uri = uri;
});
```

ChatCtrl:

```
APP.controller('ChatCtrl', function($scope, page, uri){
    uri.setActivePath('chat');

    this.detailView = function(id){
        page.setPageTitle('Chat Controller - Detail view!!');
        $scope.chatID = id;
    }

    this.listView = function(){
        page.setPageTitle('Chat Controller - List view!!');
    }

    if(uri.segment(1)) this.detailView(uri.segment(1));
    else this.listView();

});
```

Service:

```
APP.factory('page', function(){
    var title = 'Hybrid Mobile Application';

    return{
        title: function(){ return title; },
        setPageTitle: function(pageTitle){ title = pageTitle; }
    }
});
```

uri.segment(1) - get the second url segment, for eg: for /chat/235, will display 235.
ChatCtrl is used for both "/chat" and "/chat/:chatid" links and in each view I'm displaying the page.title(). So when I call the page.setPageTitle('something'), it updates the text in both header and main containers.

The problem: when I click a link from listView that goes to something like "/chat/29442", the detailView method does not update the page.title() and also the $scope.chatID is empty in this view. It only updates those values if I reload the page.

How can I make it work?

Comment: set 'title' in your factory as an object property and not a variable. then update title: value, and return the object.

Comment: nope, it's not working. `var p = { title: 'default value' }` and `return p.title` and `p.title = pageTitle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My 'uri' service was returning url path from $location, but as in 'page' service, the $location wasn't updating corectly and that's why I couldn't see the changes in page.title() and chatID.

#### The solution: $routeParams

I didn't know about this services and that's why I created one by myself to get url path(s). Now I'm using `if($routeParams.chatID) call detailView method` and everything works!